# Avoiding count explosion in querying with SPARQL ontologies containing owl:sameAs triples

Tags: sparql, owl

I am trying to build a (local) ontology that describes a finite number of objects, and that links these objects to external resources via the owl:sameAs predicate. However, when I simply query for the number of objects of that kind, I obtain twice as much as the object described. It is clear that also the external resources are counted independently, as what is taken into account is the number of URIs, and not the number of distinct objects.
I have solved this issue in the following way: I assume that the local ontology can be seen as a "reference hub" for knowing basic stuff about these objects, so I select all the objects of a certain kind, and then filter out only those that contain the base URI of the local ontology, i.e.:

```
# How many objects are there?

PREFIX ch: <http://www.example.com/ontologies/domain#>

SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT ?elem) AS ?count) WHERE {
?elem a ch:Element.
FILTER (REGEX (STR(?elem) ,"http://www.example.com/ontologies/domain") ).
}
```

However, I have two concerns with this way of doing:

1) it looks a bit of a hack (even if somehow principled), whilst I would like something that makes more logical sense

2) I have the impression that this query is not very efficient.

I have searched quite a bit here, and on google, but didn't come out with any better solution... any suggestions here?

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: As a starting note, it's worth skimming the standard of languages that you're using.  `REGEX (STR(?elem) ,"http://www.example.com/ontologies/domain") ` is presumably meant to check whether elem *starts* with [http://.../domain](), but you can just use [strstarts](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strstarts), which should be a faster, since it's much simpler.  Also, regex treats characters like . as wildcards, so you don't actually get the behavior you'd expect.

Comment: Is there any distinct attribute that these resources would have?  E.g., does each element have a distinct label?  You could add that to the query, group by it, and then count the number of labels, and *sample* the uris.

Comment: Thanks for your help Joshua! strstarts makes already the query faster! And yes, there is a label that identifies the element - you might have guessed I'm talking chemical elements. However, I'm looking for some semantic inference, how is it possible that this feature has not been implemented yet? It's an OWL statement, why is it just not taken into account? Your answer makes absolute sense of course, I'll just wait for a bit if someone has some other idea... thanks again!

Comment: "how is it possible that this feature has not been implemented yet? It's an OWL statement, why is it just not taken into account? "  SPARQL is based on RDF, and RDF doesn't have anything to do with OWL semantics.  It just happens that OWL can be serialized and mapped to RDF.  It's kind of like asking why a German dictionary doesn't contain English or French words, since the languages are written with mostly the same letters, after all.  RDF and SPARQL is like a "letter-level" representation; OWL and owl:sameAs actually require the *meaning* of some terms.

Comment: I agree. I just wonder why, depending on the entailment regime, OWL entailments can be taken into account... apart from owl:sameAs. How come?

Comment: SPARQL is the query language to query over triples.  When you have entailment possibilities, you get *more* triples.  E.g., if I know that `a p b`, once I know that `a owl:sameAs aa`, I get an *additional* triple: `aa p b`.  After all, you'd want to be able to answer "yes" to both "is it the case that a p b?" *and* "is it the case that aa p b?", right?  So if you *ask* for ?x such that  "?x p b", then you'd hope to get back at least two answers: "?x" = a and "?x = aa".  It sounds like the OWL entailment is working like it should, doesn't it?  I guess the main point is that the "DISTINCT" in

Comment: the query means "distinct syntactic elements", not "one syntactic element *per individual in an interpretation*".

Comment: Or here's a very direct case;  if you query `select distinct ?x where { ?x owl:sameAs <something> }`, you'd expect to get *multiple* results, even though all the values of ?x (based on the owl:sameAs triples) *denote* the same individual.  If distinct worked the way you're proposing it does, then you'd always get exactly one result.

Comment: of course I don't want to change how SELECT DISTINCT works. But, I wonder why another functionality, like SELECT GATHER-SAMEAS-INDIVIDUALS cannot be implemented.

Comment: One certainly could be implemented, and it might well be a nice thing to have.  However, it would depend on semantics that are beyond RDF (in this case, it would depend on OWL semantics).  That's probably why it's not in SPARQL, which is a query language for *RDF*.

Comment: actually, I thought of another option (see the updated answer for example):  you can select only those values of ?elem such that there are no "lesser" equivalent values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### GROUP BY a representative element

If there's some property that should have distinct values for each individual, then you can use it to impose the "equivalent class" structure that you need.  E.g., something like this:

```sql
prefix ch: <http://www.example.com/ontologies/domain#>

select (count(?label) as ?count) where {
  ?elem a ch:element ;
        rdfs:label ?label .
}
group by ?label
```

### Synthesize a representative element

if there's not a value that will be shared by all elements in an equivalence class, you can still *get* a representative element from the set by asking for the minimal element in each equivalence class.  We can use the IRIs of the elements to order the elements, and use that to select a *unique* individual. This does presume that each ?elem and all the things that it is the same as have well defined behavior under the **str** function (and IRIs do).

```sql
prefix ch: <http://www.example.com/ontologies/domain#>

select (count(distinct ?elem) as ?count) where {
  ?elem a ch:element .
  filter not exists {
    ?elem (owl:sameAs|^owl:sameAs)* ?elem_
    filter( str(?elem_) < str(?elem) )
  }
}
```